# Scrollbar in table shows up on top of other elements in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I've got a table that is supposed to be able to scroll underneath a persistent div at the top of the page. The content in the table is set to overflow, so one can scroll within that table itself. The problem is that the scrollbar that appears when scrolling in the table appears on top of the div underneath which the table is supposed to scroll.

[image: Here's a picture]

I'm on Chrome. And strangely enough, a friend on the same (ish) version of Chrome isn't seeing this problem at all. The problem is not present in Safari.

Full computed CSS for the div:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-clip-path: none;
-webkit-column-axis: auto;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-progression: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-filter: none;
-webkit-font-kerning: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: normal;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-line-align: none;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-line-grid: none;
-webkit-line-snap: none;
-webkit-locale: auto;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 517.5px 22.5px;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-transform: none;
-webkit-transform-origin: 517.5px 22.5px;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
align-content: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
align-self: stretch;
alignment-baseline: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: content-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: #000000;
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: row;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 45px;
image-rendering: auto;
justify-content: flex-start;
kerning: 0;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: 20px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
resize: none;
right: auto;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: start;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: auto;
width: 1035px;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

Full computed CSS for the table:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-clip-path: none;
-webkit-column-axis: auto;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-progression: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-filter: none;
-webkit-font-kerning: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: normal;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-line-align: none;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-line-grid: none;
-webkit-line-snap: none;
-webkit-locale: auto;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 411px 158px;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-transform: none;
-webkit-transform-origin: 411px 158px;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
align-content: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
align-self: stretch;
alignment-baseline: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(206, 206, 206);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: content-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: #000000;
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: row;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 300px;
image-rendering: auto;
justify-content: flex-start;
kerning: 0;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: 16px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: 300px;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 14px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
resize: none;
right: auto;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: left;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: auto;
width: 820px;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: Have you tried Z-index?

Comment: Yep, tried setting the z-index of the div to something absurdly high and no luck.

Comment: absurdly high might be too high, how high did you try and set it? I recall there being a z-index limit.

Comment: Yeah, I tried smaller z-index values as well.

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wasn't a z-index issue. It has something to do with the way OSX and Chrome handle scrollbars. I don't know the precise cause, but was able to fix the problem by styling the scollbar pseudo-element.

```
.the-table-with-offending-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 7px;
}

.the-table-with-offending-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: Amazing. This was irritating, but I had little hope of figuring out the problem and solving it myself. Thank you for sharing your solution!